# How to filter models using timezone aware dates?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

So I am trying to filter django models by date. Using either only the year, year+month, or year+month+day_of_month. The strategy I am using now is this:

```
n.filter(create_date__year=q)
n.filter(create_date__year=q[:4],create_date__month=q[4:6])
n.filter(create_date__year=q[:4],create_date__month=q[4:6],create_date__day=q[6:8])
```

Where 'q' is a date string in the format of either either 'yyyy', 'yyyymm' or 'yyyymmdd' respectively.

This is working pretty well **but** django is not taking into account timezone. Django searches based on the UTC times and not the EDT, which is what the actual datetime object is set to.

Is there a way to search the year/month/day of month based on a specific timezone?

Comment: Is q a datetime object or an actual string?

Comment: the variable q is a string right now

Comment: You should probably use a date object, then use a time zone module like pytz to query on the database. The database's timezone models use timezones automatically, which you can set in the settings file.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, when support for time zones is enabled, Django stores date and time information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

Set `USE_TZ = True` in your settings file.

Create a time-zone-aware datetime first convert it to utc and use that in your filter.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> 
>>> unaware = datetime.datetime.strptime("20131103", "%Y%m%d")
>>> amsterdam = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
>>> aware = unaware.replace(tzinfo=amsterdam)
>>> d = aware.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
>>> 
>>> unaware
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 3, 0, 0)
>>> amsterdam
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' AMT+0:20:00 STD>
>>> aware
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' AMT+0:20:00 STD>)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 2, 23, 40, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>
```

Now you can filter your objects with d.

```
objs = SomeModel.objects.all() 

objs.filter(date__year=d.year)
objs.filter(date__year=d.year, date_month=d.month)
objs.filter(date=d.date)
```

Comment: The time shift of 20 minutes should make you suspicious. Check out this thread for a correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856643/unexpected-results-converting-timezones-in-python

Comment: Will this work for datetimes like this? `d.replace(hour=8); objs.filter(datetime__hour__gte=d.hour)`

Answer (score 1):

To get the current day in a given timezone, I use the following utils function which might be useful in your case called with the `pytz.timezone("America/New_York")` argument.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def timezone_today(tz=utc):
    """
    Return the current date in the given timezone :param:`tz`.
    """
    return now().astimezone(tz).date()
```