# unexpected results converting timezones in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting these results when converting time zones to UTC:

```
In [74]: d1 = datetime(2007, 12, 5, 6, 30,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
In [75]: d1
Out[75]: datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 5, 6, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' LMT-1 day, **16:07:00 STD**>)
In [76]: d1.astimezone(pytz.utc)
Out[76]: datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 5, 14, 23, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Why did 6:30am become 2:23pm?

On the other hand, if I use the following approach, I get the expected result:

```
In [90]: d2 = datetime(2007, 12, 5, 6, 30)
In [91]: uspac = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
In [92]: d2_aware = uspac.localize(d2)
In [94]: d2_aware.astimezone(pytz.utc)
Out[94]: datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 5, 14, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: some older versions of this question: [Python datetime object show wrong timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6410971/10197418), [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the partial documentation:
http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones. [...] It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC. [...] The preferred way of dealing with times is to always work in UTC, converting to localtime only when generating output to be read by humans.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't figure this out for the life of me!

Comment: Unfortunately the statement "it is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions" is too optimistic.  It also fails for timezones whose fixed offset has changed over the years.  Fortunately UTC hasn't changed.

Answer (score 63):

What I got is just a workaround, the simple rule is **Never create datetime with timezone info by using datetime()**.

This sample would give you a hint for this. As you see, you could avoid the unexpected difference, once and only you make "naive" datetime (it is, datetime without timezone info) and then localize it (it is not applied when you create datetime on UTC though) :

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

# make Jan 1 on PDT -> UTC
pdt = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
pdtnow1 = datetime(2014,1,1, tzinfo=pdt)
pdtnow2 = pdt.localize(datetime(2014,1,1))
pytz.utc.normalize(pdtnow1)
# > datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 7, 53, tzinfo=<UTC>)
pytz.utc.normalize(pdtnow2)
# > datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 8, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

# make Jan 1 on UTC -> PDT
utcnow1 = datetime(2014,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
utcnow2 = pytz.utc.localize(datetime(2014,1,1))
pdt.normalize(utcnow1)
# > datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 16, 0, 
# > tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
pdt.normalize(utcnow2)
# > datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 16, 0, 
# > tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind when I kept seeing my results off by a few minutes. Thank you so much for this example.

Comment: @punkrockpolly My pleasure!

Comment: It was websearching for the offset 7:53 that helped me find this question. I suppose that, now that daylight savings have started for US Pacific time, seven minutes somehow got added to the offset, instead of an hour? How bizarre!

Comment: this part of python seems to be to messy to be pythonic for me

Comment: It's still problematic on convert timezone twice
`pdt.localize(datetime(2014, 1, 1) \
    .astimezone(other_timezone)`

Comment: Thanks. This is incredible. I couldn't understand why my code was 7 minutes off...

Comment: If the year of your date is before 1901, you will still have issues with the minutes being off Eg: `pdt.localize(datetime(1900,1,1))`
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2wd35a/comment/copuhtx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, creating timezone aware dates using this method doesn't work.

If you are using Django, they have a utility function, [make_aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware), that does this correctly.

```
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware
from pytz import timezone

unaware_datetime = datetime(2007, 12, 5)
local_datetime = make_aware(datetime(2007, 12, 5))
specific_datetime = make_aware(datetime(2007, 12, 5), timezone("Australia/Melbourne"))
```

If you're not using Django, then the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/timezone.py#L264) for the make_aware function may give you inspiration.

Comment: Django's `make_aware(dt)` is just calling `pytz.timezone(...).localize(dt)`

Answer (score 4):

I'm revisiting some questions about date and time to see if some of the newer libraries prove more helpful in situations like this (or not). [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) is one that stores timezone with date and time, making it particularly valuable in situations such as this.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> d1 = pendulum.datetime(2007,12,5,6,30, tzinfo='US/Pacific')
>>> d1
<Pendulum [2007-12-05T06:30:00-08:00]>
>>> d1.timezone
<Timezone [US/Pacific]>
>>> d1.astimezone(tz='UTC')
<Pendulum [2007-12-05T14:30:00+00:00]>
```

Lots of other sweet features too.

Answer (score 0):

Print `d2_aware` before `.astimezone` and you see `PST-1` (Pacific Standard Time) but in first example you have `LMT-1` (Local Mean Time) - and probably it can give 7 minutes difference.

But I don't know why `pytz` use different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.9, the recommended way *is to create datetime with timezone info by using `datetime()`*, contrary to what was the case when the currently top-rated answer was posted. However, instead of using the 3rd party library `pytz`, you should now instead use [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#using-zoneinfo) from the standard library.

```py
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> dt = datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
>>> print(dt)
2020-10-31 12:00:00-07:00

>>> dt.tzname()
'PDT'
```