# datetime + pytz: Converting times across timezones fails

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I am not sure what is going wrong with the following snippet of code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
time_us_pacific = datetime(2017, 3, 16, 14, 30).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))
time_india = time_us_pacific.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))
print(time_india)
# Actual: 2017-03-17 03:53:00+05:30
# Expected: 2017-03-17 03:00:00+05:30

# Picking a date before DST switch:
time_us_pacific = datetime(2017, 2, 16, 14, 30).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))
time_india = time_us_pacific.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))
print(time_india)
# Actual: 2017-03-17 03:53:00+05:30
# Expected: 2017-03-17 04:00:00+05:30
```

There seem to be two issues:

1. `pytz` timezones are not accounting for DST
2. The India timezone seems
   to prefer the more arcane local mean time (LMT) as opposed to Indian
   Standard Time

My application needs to do some serious timezone-based accounting of events and cannot afford to screw things up. My questions are:

1. Am I using Python `datetime` and `pytz` incorrectly?
2. Should I be using something else in place of `pytz`?

Thanks for any help or insights.

Comment: Hi @Raj, it is a known defect as [its highlighted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25390097/227884). Gist of the answer is: `datetime(..).replace(tzinfo=timezone_object)` should not be used. if you rewrite as: `timezone_object.localize(datetime(.....))`, you wont have that issue.

Comment: Thanks @SuperSaiyan! This works!