# Timezone aware dates

Tags: python, datetime

I am a bit confused between the following:

```
import datetime
import pytz
str(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')))
str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')))
```

In the first case I get:
'2018-08-10 14:21:04.129204-07:00'
and in the second case I get '2018-08-10 14:21:17.856903-07:53'
I am a bit confused on why the dont return the same time offsets?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856643/unexpected-results-converting-timezones-in-python/25390097

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you are passing

```
pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
```

As function argument of

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

In the second line you are

```
.replacing
```

The return of

```
 datetime.datetime.now()
```

With

```
pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
```

I advise you to research into the pytz library documents : https://pypi.org/project/pytz/

My guess is that the first function the pytz out put is being formated to human readable by datetime.now()

In the second line you are just replacing the return, hence is shown as Unix time